# Wordpress Cookie sharing issue with different IPs

Tags: wordpress, cors, subdomain, setcookie

I am facing some issues while sharing the cookie between wordpress and reactjs application.

The following are the example IPs for frontend and wordpress:

- Frontend server IP address : https://165.23.115.114
- Wordpress server IP address: http://179.68.87.7

If I login from the reactjs application or wordpress and vice-versa then wordpress logged in cookie will be shared with reactjs application which we are not getting.

I am using the GRAPHQL and GRAPHQL cors masters plugin at wordpress end. I am integrating the wordpress login at reactjs application.

The following is the CORS plugin for reference:
https://github.com/funkhaus/wp-graphql-cors

But, Cookie is shared at my local server perfectly but not at live server.
For local using the following:

- Reactjs - http://localhost:3000
- Wordpress: http://localhost

I have added the SSL on both the IPs.
And I also find it there might be some CORS issue.

This is my CORS setting for GRAPHQL its for local but same i did for live only changed the IPs

[image]

I want to make cookie sharing or set cookie at live server too.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to share cookies between *origins*. You Can't Do That™. You need to find some other way to share state.

An origin is a server. Examples of origins include `https://stackoverflow.com/`, `http://example.com/`, `http://localhost/`, and the ones you mentioned.

The [documentation for cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie) says

> The domain must match the domain of the JavaScript origin. Setting cookies to foreign domains will be silently ignored.

Comment: You wrote: _You're trying to share cookies between origins. You Can't Do That™._ That's a bit imprecise. This may be true in the OP's case, but cookies are in general not origin-bound. In the example of a cookie created with cookie attribute `Domain=stackoverflow.com`, browsers will send it to both `https://stackoverflow.com` and `https://foo.stackoverflow.com`.